# ¿Qué palabra podemos usar para indicar que nos quitamos una pieza de ropa?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Estaba explicando que mi hija se había quitado un calcetín más o menos sin querer cuando me surgió la duda: ¿tenemos en castellano alguna palabra más concreta para definir el hecho de dejar de llevar una pieza de ropa?

- *Desnudar* para mí tiene la connotación de quedar desnudo.
- *Quitarse* me parece demasiado genérica y el último recurso.
- *[Desprender](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DP6xpgu)* me gusta algo más, pero así y todo me suena más relacionado con objetos inanimados unidos entre sí: *el cuadro se desprendió de la pared*.

¿Se os ocurre alguna palabra que sea más específica?

La frase en la que se usaría diría algo así como:

> Mi hija se XXX los calcetines al poco de ponérselos, pues no dejaba de
>   mover los pies contra la cuna.

Comment: Piensa a la inversa. ¿Qué verbo utilizarías para el hecho contrario? "Ponerse" sin duda es la palabra más lógica, de hecho, es la que usas en tu frase de ejemplo. Entonces... ¿qué problema hay con usar "quitarse" como opuesto a "ponerse"? Es sin duda la mejor opción y la más natural. Otra cosa es que por estilismo quieras ir a opciones más sonoras y menos naturales "desprenderse", "despojarse",... pero estas opciones sólo parecen mejores en texto escrito y en circunstancias muy especiales.

Comment: @Bardo gracias por el comentario, la verdad es que pones un sentido común que tal vez me faltó al pensar la pregunta : ) Eso sí, el matiz que no resalté suficientemente es el hecho de que este "quitarse" sea de forma más o menos involuntaria.

Comment: Para hacer referencia a que se quita algo sin darse cuenta o de un modo automático yo suelo usar "se le caen", es una opción bastante de andar por casa, pero si el contexto está claro y la frase bien construida se entiende perfectamente.

Comment: Pues yo acabo de dejar mi +1, porque para mi es una pregunta que puede aportar bastante. Si bien "quitarse" es lo que yo habría usado (sin dudarlo) la pregunta me hizo investigar un poco y aprender sobre otras opciones o sinónimos más rebuscados. La que aporto en mi respuesta, `remover` no es la que yo usaría tampoco, pero aprendí que la palabra se puede usar también con el sentido de "quitar algo de una sitio". Por lo tanto, considero que esta pregunta es útil para este sitio.

Comment: No lo considero una respuesta completa, ya que es demasiado circunstancial, de ahi que lo pongo como comentario. En el caso de quitarse un calcetín de manera involuntaria y debido a no estarse quiet@, yo diría que **se le cayó el calcetín**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo usaría "quitarse" (como sugieren muchas de las otras respuestas). También entiendo que "quitarse" tiene cierta connotación de voluntariedad, y quieres expresar que la acción de *desprenderse* del calcetín fue involuntaria, mientras la niña dormía.

En cualquier caso, puestos a responder la pregunta con "**qué otras opciones hay**" (y aprender algo nuevo sobre nuestra lengua) he de decir que tu pregunta me hizo pensar en `remover`. Estaba casi seguro de que era un anglicismo, pero al buscarlo en el RAE, vi que [remover](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=EUmbk4il1DXX2Z5eS7nP) puede tener el significado de

> Quitar, apartar u obviar un inconveniente.

e incluso

> apartar a alguien de su empleo o destino
>
> mudar algo de un lugar a otro

E incluso en el DPD podemos encontrar

> **Remover**
>
> 2. **No hay por qué censurar su empleo con los sentidos de ‘quitar [algo] de un lugar’** y ‘apartar [a alguien] de su cargo’, suponiendo, erróneamente, que se trata de un calco del inglés to remove: «Librar a este país de ese hombre, eso era lo principal. Removido ese obstáculo [...], se abriría una puerta» (VLlosa Fiesta [Perú 2000]); «Sus jefes tendrían la facultad de designar o remover coroneles y capitanes» (Otero Temporada [Cuba 1983]). Son acepciones tradicionales en español, ya presentes en el étimo latino: «Tales deven ser removidos de la aministraçión fasta que fagan buena penitençia» (Cuéllar Catecismo [Esp. 1325]).
>
> Fuente: [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas ©2005 / RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=remover)

[Investigando un poco más](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/remover-%C2%BFanglicismo.265798/) aprendí que `remover` puede ser un anglicismo cuando se usa con el sentido de "borrar" o "eliminar" (una traducción directa de, por ejemplo, "**Remove** that file from the system", que ya ha sido por cierto [preguntado en este sitio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2075/5481)).

Si bien, soy el primero en admitir que si dijeses

> Mi hija se **ha removido** los calcetines al poco de ponérselos

tu interlocutor te iba a mirar como a un bicho raro, y pensaría que estás hablando *spanglish* aunque no sea el caso.

Comment: ¡Siempre se aprende un montón de tus respuestas!

Answer (score 7):

Pienso que la traducción tiene que ser considerando el usuario final, y en este caso "se quitó" del verbo quitarse es lo más utilizado por el hispanohablante.

> Mi hija se quitó los calcetines al poco tiempo de ponérselos, pues no
>   dejaba de mover los pies contra la cuna.

Answer (score 6):

«Quitarse» es una voz perfecta para «los calcetines».

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Sería bueno que añadieras algún tipo de razonamiento, enlace o, en general, algo más para dar mayor consistencia a la respuesta. Si no, apenas es un [buen] comentario.

Comment: Gracias, fedorqui. Todavía estoy aprendiendo a usar este maravilloso recurso que es Stack Exchange, y por ello tal vez he cometido ciertos errorcillos como el anterior. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar **desvestir**.

El significado de *desnudar* según el DRAE, es sinónimo de **desvestir** y no necesariamente significa *quitarse toda la ropa*:

> 1. tr. Quitar todo el vestido o parte de él. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Despojar algo de lo que lo cubre o adorna. Desnudar los altares, los árboles.
>
>    *[Fuente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DE5xV5I)*

Pero te sugiero cambiar la oración así:

> Mi hija se desnudó los pies al poco de ponerse los calcetines.

Comment: Creo que es la palabra más apropida.

Answer (score 4):

Pueda que esta palabra te pueda servir: despojarse

> 4. prnl. desnudarse (‖ quitarse el vestido) *o los calcetines en tu caso*.
> 5. prnl. Desposeerse de algo voluntariamente.

En tu caso sería:

> *"Mi hija se **despojó** de los calcetines al poco de ponérselos, pues no dejaba de mover los pies contra la cuna."*